# How do I return my List

Tags: java, list

This code works according to test cases. I have to get my `getList()` function to return my List. The problem is that it won't return the list because the size of the List = 0. The size can't increase because according to my test cases the `addURLID(int urlID)` method can't add to the List until the size of the List is at least 1. Any type of help would be appreciated especially in `getList()`.

```
import java.io.Serializable;
import java.util.ArrayList;
import java.util.List;

public class Word extends Object implements Serializable {

    private List<Integer> postings = new ArrayList<>();
    static long serialVersionUID = -3696191086353573895L;
    private String word;
    private int urlID;

    public Word(String word, int urlID) {
        this.word = word;
        this.urlID = urlID;
    }

    public void addURLID(int urlID) {
        postings.add(urlID);
    }

    public List<Integer> getList(){
        List<Integer> postings = new ArrayList<>();
        return postings;
    }
}
```

Comment: That code won't compile.  Please post real code.

Comment: And explain the question a little clearer.

Comment: Joseph - don't vandalize your Question by "fixing" the problem you were asking about.  It renders the Answers meaningless.

Answer (score 1):

Your `getList()` method, is creating a completely new list locally and returning it to the calling function. Thus it will always return an empty list.

 instead, you must simply return the existing list (attribute of class)

```
public List<Integer> getList(){
    return this.postings;
}
```